Implementation of timeout in APIs
I have a function that I use to make API calls in my codebase but I am unable to make the timeout part work. Everything else is fine but timeout just doesn't work it just loops then after a while stops I am guessing theres a default somewhere that is failing. Any pointers on where I have messed up the implementation of timeout.
async def services():
    global session6

    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(
        limit=50,  # Maximum number of simultaneous connections
        ttl_dns_cache=300,  # DNS cache time-to-live in seconds
        force_close=False,  # Whether to force close connections on release
        enable_cleanup_closed=True,  # Whether to enable cleanup of closed connections
        keepalive_timeout=20 

    )
    
    if session6 is None:
        logger.debug(' Generating New Session',extra={'traceId': uuid.uuid4(),'resource':resource,'spanId':uuid.uuid4(),'event_timestamp':time.time_ns()})
        connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector()
        session6 = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector)

    return session6

async def api_request(trace_id, url, method, retry_limit=3, timeout=2, interval=2, protocol='https', **kwargs):
    """
    Make an API call using aiohttp with retries and specified parameters.

    :param trace_id: Unique identifier for the trace.
    :param url: The API endpoint URL.
    :param method: The HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).
    :param retry_limit: Number of retry attempts.
    :param timeout: Timeout for each API call in seconds.
    :param interval: Interval between retries in seconds.
    :param protocol: The default Protocol to use if not provided (http or https).
    :param kwargs: Additional arguments to pass to the request (e.g., headers, data, json).
    :return: A dictionary containing status_code and response_data.
    """
    try:
    
        # Ensure the URL starts with http or https
        if not url.startswith(('http://', 'https://')):
            url = f'{protocol}://' + url

        async def fetch(session, url, method, timeout, **kwargs):
            try:
                if method.upper() == 'GET':
                    async with session.get(url, timeout=ClientTimeout(total=timeout), **kwargs) as response:
                        response_data = await response.json()
                        return {'status_code': response.status, 'response_data': response_data}
                elif method.upper() == 'POST':
                    async with session.post(url, timeout=ClientTimeout(total=timeout), **kwargs) as response:
                        response_data = await response.json()
                        return {'status_code': response.status, 'response_data': response_data}
                elif method.upper() == 'PUT':
                    async with session.put(url, timeout=ClientTimeout(total=timeout), **kwargs) as response:
                        response_data = await response.json()
                        return {'status_code': response.status, 'response_data': response_data}
                elif method.upper() == 'DELETE':
                    async with session.delete(url, timeout=ClientTimeout(total=timeout), **kwargs) as response:
                        response_data = await response.json()
                        return {'status_code': response.status, 'response_data': response_data}
                else:
                    raise ValueError(f"Unsupported HTTP method: {method}")
            except aiohttp.ClientError as e:
                logger.info(
                    f'Client error: {e}',
                    extra={'traceId': trace_id, 'resource':resource,'spanId': trace_id, 'event_timestamp': time.time_ns()}
                )
                raise
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                logger.error("Request timed out", extra={'traceId': trace_id})
                logger.info(
                    'Request timed out',
                    extra={'traceId': trace_id, 'resource':resource,'spanId': trace_id, 'event_timestamp': time.time_ns()}
                )
                raise

        for attempt in range(retry_limit):
            try:
                session = await services()
                logger.info(
                    f'API Request ====> url={url} || method={method} || Retry Attempt={attempt} || Retry Limit={retry_limit} || Timeout={timeout} || Retry Interval={interval} || Request Details={kwargs}',
                    extra={'traceId': trace_id, 'resource':resource,'spanId': trace_id, 'event_timestamp': time.time_ns()}
                )
                response = await fetch(session, url, method, timeout, **kwargs)
                logger.info(
                    f'API Response ====> url={url} || method={method} || Retry Attempt={attempt} || Retry Limit={retry_limit} || Timeout={timeout} || Retry Interval={interval} || Response Details={response}',
                    extra={'traceId': trace_id, 'resource':resource, 'spanId': trace_id, 'event_timestamp': time.time_ns()}
                )
                return response
            except (aiohttp.ClientError, asyncio.TimeoutError) as e:
                if attempt < retry_limit - 1:
                    logger.info(
                    f'Retrying in {interval} seconds... (Attempt {attempt + 1} of {retry_limit})',
                    extra={'traceId': trace_id, 'resource':resource, 'spanId': trace_id, 'event_timestamp': time.time_ns()}
                )
                    await asyncio.sleep(interval)
                else:
                    logger.info(
                    'Exceeded retry limit.',
                    extra={'traceId': trace_id, 'resource':resource, 'spanId': trace_id, 'event_timestamp': time.time_ns()}
                )
                    raise ApiResponse(f"API Request Limit Exhausted for url={url}", trace_id, 5002  , [{"field": url,
                            "error_message":kwargs}])

    
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e).__name__,  __file__, e.__traceback__.tb_lineno ,e.args)
        logger.critical(f'Error during ECS HTTP get request- {type(e).__name__,  __file__, e.__traceback__.tb_lineno ,e.args}',extra={'traceId': trace_id,'resource':'resource','spanId':trace_id,'event_timestamp':time.time_ns()})
        return {"status_code": 500,"response_data": f"connection_error to {url}","message": str(e)}


When you say "timeout just doesn't work" -- what do you mean by doesn't work? Is it possible that all of the requests are timing out? Are your logs filled with your "Retrying in ..." messages? I believe that aiohttp timeouts have changed to aiohttp.ClientTimeout objects rather than floats (see https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientTimeout). Floats still work for backward compatibility, but they set the total request time, not the connect time. 2 seconds could just be too short. Have you tried a longer timeout?
